# Injecting field into module using dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger

I am trying to inject my android context from one module into another. This is my code so far:

UserProfileModule.java

```
@Module(
        library = true
)
public class UserProfileModule {

    @Inject Context _context;

    @Provides
    public AccountUtils.UserProfile provideUserProfile() {
        return AccountUtils.getUserProfile(_context);
    }
}
```

RootModule.java

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                PizzaApplication.class,
                UserProfileModule.class,
                MainActivity.class
        },
        includes = {
                UserProfileModule.class
        },
        library = true
)

public class RootModule {
    private final Context _context;

    public RootModule(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return _context;
    }
}
```

Anytime it tries to get the user profile it fails saying the object is null.]

EDIT:

PizzaApplication.java

```
public class PizzaApplication extends Application {
    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        injectDependencies();
    }

    private void injectDependencies() {
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new RootModule(this));
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        objectGraph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar) public Toolbar _toolbar;
    @InjectView(R.id.drawer) public DrawerFrameLayout _drawer;
    @Inject public AccountUtils.UserProfile _profile;
    @Inject public Context _context;

    // private NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
```

Comment: Start by removing `library = true` from the modules. What errors do you get, if any?

Comment: Also, what is the code you're using to inject your instances?

Comment: Removing `library = true` just brings up an error saying I am not using the provideUserProfile provider.

Comment: Are you? This error is not to be "fixed" by adding `library = true`,  but by actually using the provider. Do you have any code which uses this provider?

Comment: I am trying to inject it into my activity as added above. Should I be using a constructor instead of a field?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. You should actually inject the instances yourself. In your activity, call 'objectGraph.inject(this)`. See the documentation on dagger for an example.

Comment: I am. In the oncreate for the baseactivity it calls that method. Sorry I didn't include that.

Comment: Could you also add how you build your ObjectGraph?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71412/discussion-between-coder2000-and-niek-haarman).

Comment: I  currently not in a position to use the chat unfortunately.

Comment: I have created a gist with all the code if it makes is easier to read: https://gist.github.com/coder2000/38aafaaa2f5a2edcb6de

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr (Short version):

1. For a minimal working example of your code, see [my code on GitHub](https://github.com/glombard/so/tree/master/28651474_dagger/app/src/main/java/com/codeblast/dagger)
2. You don't need to / should't inject the `Context` from one module into another.
3. The order/direction of your module `includes` is reversed, the UserProfileModule should include the RootModule.

More details and comments on your code:

1. You don't need to inject something into a module, a module only provides dependencies. In your case simply making use of the module `includes` gives the functionality you want.
2. Remove the `library = true` from `UserProfileModule`, because you only need this when the module's providers aren't all used directly by the classes specified in the `injects` list.
3. As Niek Haarman said, you need to pass both `RootModule` and `UserProfileModule` instances to `ObjectGraph.create` in your PizzaApplication's onCreate.
4. You're doing `inject(this)` in PizzaApplication but it's got no dependencies, so the inject isn't necessary. Based on the sample code you've provided, this makes me think you're assuming that injecting on the Application-level will also inject Activity dependencies...? You need to do the inject on your Activity too.
5. You don't show if you're doing an inject in your Activity's onCreate -- that's most likely what's missing.
6. You're injecting Context into the Activity but that's not necessary since you can just use getApplicationContext() in the Activity.

Here's the working code:

**RootModule:**

```
@Module(
    injects = {MainActivity.class},
    library = true,
    complete = false
)
public class RootModule {
  private final Context _context;

  public RootModule(Context context) {
    _context = context;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public Context provideApplicationContext() {
    return _context;
  }
}
```

**UserProfileModule:**

```
@Module(includes = {RootModule.class})
public class UserProfileModule {
  @Provides
  public AccountUtils.UserProfile provideUserProfile(Context context) {
    return AccountUtils.getUserProfile(context);
  }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

  @Inject
  public AccountUtils.UserProfile _profile;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((PizzaApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
    _profile.message();
  }
```

**PizzaApplication:**

```
public class PizzaApplication extends Application {
  private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new RootModule(this), new UserProfileModule());
  }

  public void inject(Object object) {
    objectGraph.inject(object);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new RootModule(this));
```

But,  `includes = { UserProfileModule.class }` is no magic. You have to create it yourself:

```
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new RootModule(this), new UserProfileModule() );
```

Furthermore, the `@Inject` annotation on the `Context` doesn't work. You're better off modifying your provider method:

```
@Provides 
public AccountUtils.UserProfile provideUserProfile(Context context) { 
    return AccountUtils.getUserProfile(context);
}
```

I cannot guarantee this will solve all your problems, but it will help you in the right direction.